# Why variables sum returns multiplication?

Tags: c, arrays, operations

in the following code:

```
void fusioneArray(int v[], int vL, int w[], int wL[], int *fusione)
{
   int i,j,temp;
   int k=0;
   printf("%d",wL+vL);

   for(i=0;i<vL;i++)
   {
       fusione[k]=v[i];
       k++;
   }

   for(j=0;j<wL;j++)
   {
       fusione[k]=w[j];
       k++;
   }
}

int main()
{
    int v[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int w[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
    int i=0;
    int fusione[10];
    fusioneArray(v,5,w,5,fusione);
}
```

can u explain me why vL+wL returns * instead of +? (25 instead of 10)...

Comment: `int wL[]`? Did you mean `int wL`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `wL` is a pointer in your code, thus you're doing pointer arithmetics instead of a standard integer arithmetics :

wL+vL = wL + vL*sizeof(int)

Since a `int` is 4-bytes on most platforms your `wL+vL` becomes `5+5*4 = 25`, which is the result you get. Simply replace `int wL[]` with the correct `int wL` and you'll have the desired behavior.

Comment: And sometimes even more hilariously left field than that, since it's a compiler-defined sort of thing. When I get massive negative numbers on simple arithmetic, I know I screwed up pointers somewhere.